# $T$ is onto, but $T(\beta)$ is not a basis for $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been stuck on this question for some time, and I can't seem to figure it out.

The question is asking to find an example of V, W, T and $\beta$ such that T is onto, but T($\beta$) is not a basis of W. V and W are vectors and T:V $\rightarrow$ W is linear.

I know that if T is onto, then this implies that R(T)=W. However, I don't know how to find a basis T($\beta$) for R(T) without having it generate W. I've tried loads of random transformations but nothing seems to be working out for me and I always end up having T($\beta$) generating W.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Well, some elements of $\beta$ might go to zero... Can you think of a case when this happens?

Comment: Or, they could go to the same element.

Comment: I think it's wrong.  If you have $w\in W$ then choose some $v\in T^{-1}(\{w\})$ (i.e. $T(v)=w$), now you have $v=\sum_{i\in F} \alpha_i b_i$ (for $F$ finite, $\alpha_i$ scalars and $b_i\in\beta$), but $w=T(v)=T(\sum_{i\in F} \alpha_i b_i)=\sum_{i\in F}\alpha_i T(b_i)$ so the $T(b)$ generate $W$.

Comment: @fweth yes, the $T(e_i)$s of course generate $W$, as the image of a base completely determines the linear transformation, that's not the issue. The thing is that those vectors might not be linearly independent to form a base.

Comment: Oh wait, would I be correct in thinking that I need a transformation that sends at least one element to 0? Would a transformation such as $ R^2 \rightarrow R^3 $,  $ T(a_1,a_2) = (a_1,a_2,0) $ work?

Comment: @TFSM That's not onto. To be more explicit, to find a transformation $T: V\to W$  that works you'll need that $\dim V> \dim W$. Why is this? Well, you need $\dim W$ vectors to generate $W$, then you need at least one more (to "waste it") in order for your transformation not to be a bijection.

Comment: OK, sorry, I see!  But the OP wrote in the last paragraph 'I always end up having $T(\beta)$ generating $W$, I was merely answering to this claim!

Comment: @fweth The question doesn't mention it, but we aren't supposed to use infinite vectors or basis. Thanks though!

Comment: @TFSM Is there anything you don't understand about my answer? I'll make it clearer if so.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yeah, I've been trying to figure it out for a while and I don't think I quite get it. Sorry! I can be a little slow sometimes

Comment: @TFSM No problems. Getting into understanding linear transformations is one of the most fundamental parts of linear algebra, it's tricky when starting, but once you get a grasp of all the concepts, it becomes a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Call $\beta$ the standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Consider the following linear transformation

$$
T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R\\
T(0,0,1)=1\\
T(0,1,0)=2\\
T(1,0,0)=3\\
$$

Why does this work?

It seems you're confusing basis with set of generators, you should recheck your definitions.

E: If you want, the above transformation looks like
$$
T(x,y,z)=3x+2y+1z
$$
In more traditional notation.

From above, we see that $T(\beta)=\{1,2,3\}$. This set surely generates the vector space $\Bbb R$, but it fails the linearly independent condition because 
$$
-2\cdot(1)+1\cdot(2)+0\cdot(3)=0
$$
Thus $T(\beta)$ is not a basis of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Hmm I think so. I know a basis is a linear independent set of vectors that generate V. I think what I meant in the question is that I've tried random transformations that are onto and T($\beta$) ended up generating W for all of them. 

I'm also not really sure why your linear transformation works. I'm guessing the transformation is $ 3_a1 + 2a_2 + a_3 $?

Comment: @TFSM  Check my edit, I think I answered most your doubts.

Comment: OH, now I see what you meant! Thank you so much!